# Drag and drop the application to another monitor screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which fits to full screen mode in my monitor (1920 X 1080) resolution on loading of the form. Once it loads, I will drag the application to another monitor having (1600 X 900) resolution (2 monitors connected to same PC). All the controls will be loosing their location and will be like hidden. Please anybody provide solution for this?

Comment: Is this on `Windows Form`? The question is rather general otherwise.

Comment: yes its a windows form application

Comment: The form will have to resized or maximized on the second monitor. Then handle the on resize event of your form and reposition your controls.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am trying on it

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be more efficiently solved depends on how your format look like.

But generally, you need:

1. Good way to format your Form, such that it is "robust" against changeable screen size.

   you can check the `Container` on `Windows Form` like `Panel`, `FlowLayoutPanel`, or `TableLayoutPanel` as well as `SplitContainer` and `Splitter`.

   All those tools help you to format how your app look.
2. Flexible way to put and to size your control.

   You can learn more about WinForm `Control` property called `Dock` and `Size` to help you put and size your control. And lastly,
3. Event handler for the `Resize` event of the `Form` (and in more complex case, `Resize` of the `Container`

   There is a limit on what the automatic formatting can do to you. This event handler is to handle whatever you think it cannot be properly handled by all the built-in properties.

You can also learn about BootStrapping. It may help you to format your app.